# How to set dynamic style properties in EJS?

Tags: html, css, node.js, ejs

I am using EJS render engine for sending mails from Node. I need to set the background color, text color and other properties dynamically.

something like `style ="background: <%=primary_color%>"`

or if we can dynamically select the class

`class="<%=primary_class%>"`

Comment: any answer for this ?

Answer (score 3):

You could pass background colors from a node.js express server and `ejs.renderFile`.

```js
//server.js

let bgColors = { 
  primary: '#000',
  accent: '#fff',
  gray: '#eee'
}

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  ejs.renderFile('home.ejs', {bgColors}, {}, (err, template) => {
      if (err) throw err
      res.end(template)
  })
})
```

Then in the home html file you can use the attribute names of the `bgColors`.

```html
<div style="background: <%= bgColors.primary %>">Some text</div>

<div style="background: <%= bgColors.accent %>">Some more text</div>

<div style="background: <%= bgColors.gray %>">Some more text</div>
```