# Can i use ejs for render values from server and use it as an attribute value inside html TAG?

Tags: html, css, node.js, express, ejs

Anyone help me with this? How to do this ?[this is my app.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGmUL.png)[This is my index.ejs file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbWHz.png)

```
<h1 style="color:'<%= color %>'">
```

I also tried like this,but did not get result as expected.

Comment: try this way `<h1 style="color:<%= color %>">` check here too
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65938487/how-to-set-dynamic-style-properties-in-ejs

Comment: Tried already but no effect.Shows at-rule or selector expected

Answer (score 0):

i changed color value to "color:red"
[and used inside H1 Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqkcF.png)

Now its working.